# Call python file with optional parameters

Tags: python-2.7, sys

I would like to keep the same name of my script, but have one for automatic execution (which would not take any parameters), and one for ad hoc execution (which would take parameters).  Would something like the code below work?

```
#myPythonFile.py
import sys

def main():
  if argv[1] is None:
    #Do something
  elif:
    #Do something else


if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

Then I could either call

```
myPythonFile.py
```

or

```
myPythonFile.py 'param1', 'param2'
```

correct?

Comment: For positional arguments, please use https://docs.python.org/2/howto/argparse.html You can specify default actions and values

Comment: So I should use the above if i have multiple combinations of parameters that are position dependent, but if its just an all or nothing, there are arguments or not, then what i have is fine, right?

Comment: @PyNoob That makes sense to me, @roymustang86's answer is more complete but may be more than you need. You may however get an `index out of bounds` error the way its written. Maybe write `if len(argv) <= 1` instead to check if no params are passed.

Comment: Also there is no need for comma between arguments when passing it to the python script.

Comment: good call on the exception, rbierman.  Thanks everyone for your help

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can check arguments passed:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys

print 'Number of arguments:', len(sys.argv), 'arguments.'
print 'Argument List:', str(sys.argv)
```

Here is how it would work

```
~$ ./arg.py 1 2 3
Number of arguments: 4 arguments.
Argument List: ['./arg.py', '1', '2', '3']
~$ ./arg.py  2 3
Number of arguments: 3 arguments.
Argument List: ['./arg.py', '2', '3']
```

If you use optparse or argeparse however:

```
def process_arguments():
    """
    Process our command line arguments, the "master" config file,
    and the file holding one or more database connection strings.
    """
    parser = OptionParser()

    parser.add_option('--input', '-i',
                      type='string',
                      dest='input_file',
                      action='store',
                      default='something',
                      help='The input file for method')

    parser.add_option('--output', '-o',
                      type='string',
                      dest='output_file',
                      action='store',
                      default='anythig',
                      help='The output file for method')

    parser.add_option('--debug', '-d',
                      type='string',
                      dest='debug',
                      action='store',
                      default=None,
                      help='Optional debug argument')

    opts, args = parser.parse_args()
    return opts, args
if __name__ == '__main__':
    options, arguments = process_arguments()
    print options, arguments
```

Here is how it would look

```
~$ ./opt.py
{'input_file': 'something', 'output_file': 'nothing', 'debug': None}
[]

~$ ./opt.py -i file_name dir_name
{'input_file': 'file_name', 'output_file': 'nothing', 'debug': None}
['dir_name']
```